# Do I need a credit card to apply for a visa to Norway?

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, norway, uk-residents, chinese-citizens

I am a Chinese citizen, and I currently live and work in the United Kingdom after studying there.

I am following the steps at [UDI](https://www.udi.no/) in order to apply for a visa to visit Norway. While following the instructions, I clicked on the link *UK checklist common* which one can find [here](https://www.norway.no/en/uk/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/visitors-visa/#necessary-doc). This leads to a document and the list *1. General Requirements*. One of the items in this list is *Credit card(s) and credit card account statement in your name*.

I do not have a credit card, but I do have a debit card.

Is it necessary for me to obtain a credit card to travel to Norway using this application form?

Comment: IDK but perhaps they require a credit card as evidence of financial stability, and the ability to draw immediately on funds (if unexpectedly needed) which might not be present in the account to which the debit card has access.

Comment: The guidance states “please provide a written explanation for why you can not submit the required documents”. Even in this era of easy credit many people do not have a credit card, to me it seems unlikely you would be refused a visa simply because of that, providing your bank statements show a healthy balance.

Comment: @Traveller Good observation. I will bring a written explanation as you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I added a statement to the application explaining that I do not have a credit card. My visa application was accepted and I received a valid visa for travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While credit cards are listed on the checklist, it's best to clarify directly with the UDI if a debit card with sufficient funds would be acceptable proof of financial resources. They can provide the most accurate and up-to-date information specific to your situation. I also think every situation is different, in my case I got approved the first time when I applied for a visa in Norway even without a credit card. But I was denied when I applied the second time.

Comment: Was lack of a credit card the reason for the denial?